# JAXB: Anonymous simple types as enums?

Tags: binding, xsd, jaxb

When generating Java from an XSD via the XJC compiler, I always get the type java.lang.String for elements with anonymous simpleTypes like this:

```
    <xsd:element name="Product">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="Product1"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="Product2"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="Product3"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

Of course, I want an enumeration for this. Is there a way to trick XJC into generating and using one?

We are using JAXB 2.1.3.
Note: before you ask, no, I cannot change the schema and adapt it to XJC's bugs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to put into your XJC File:

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='Product']/xsd:simpleType">
    <jxb:typesafeEnumClass name="ProductType" />
</jxb:bindings>
```

or

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='Produkt']">
    <jxb:bindings node="./xsd:simpleType">
        <jxb:typesafeEnumClass name="ProduktType" />
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of how I implemented this. I will add the whole xjb for completeness since I admit looking at existing examples I still found it a little confusing.

Here´s the .xjb file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               jaxb:version="1.0">
   <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="search-constraints.xsd" 
    node="/xs:schema">

     <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='booleanStringType']">
      <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass name="BooleanStringType" />
  </jaxb:bindings>

   </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Here, the bindings refer to my simple types which are declared at root level in my search-constraints.xsd. Here is an extract of that file:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 targetNamespace="http://www.example.com" 
 xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com" 
 elementFormDefault="qualified"
 xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jaxb:version="1.0">

...


<xs:simpleType name="booleanStringType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="true" />
        <xs:enumeration value="false" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar question, I asked on the JAXB mailing list and got [this fairly helpful response](https://java.net/projects/jaxb/lists/users/archive/2009-02/message/17) (haven't had time to try it out though)

edit: if you're talking about *automatically generating* the enum class, rather than just automatically mapping to an enum class you write yourself, I would think that you could write a java class that would parse the schema file and autogenerate the java code for that enumeration. (then run that java class whenever you call xjc)

Comment: I managed to do this without defining my own enum type - see my answer.