# JAXB does not create enum for restricted element

Tags: enums, jaxb, xsd, restriction

I need some help with my xsd and jaxb.

My xsd leads to an working class (MyWorkingType) and the 'ProblemType', which is not generated with an enum.

As I believe, that both forms are valid, why does this not work, where is the bug (jaxb or at the keyboard?)

**Edit:** I add my ant-script, because Xtian could create this via maven-plugin.

This is my xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="ProblemType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="normalAttribute" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="enumAttribute">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_1" />
                        <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_2" />
                        <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_3" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="workingEnum">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_1" />
            <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_2" />
            <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_3" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="MyWorkingType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="normalAttribute" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="enumAttribute" type="workingEnum" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

This is my ant-script I use within eclipse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="generate" default="generate-jaxb" basedir=".">
    <taskdef name="xjc" classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="../lib" includes="*.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="generate-jaxb">
        <xjc destdir="../../src-gen" package="test.gen">
            <arg value="-no-header" />
            <schema dir="xsd/" includes="*.xsd"/>
        </xjc>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you asking _why_ creating an anonymous type doesn't create an enum or why _your_ schema definition create an enum field in ProductType?

Comment: Sry, I am asking, why ProblemType is not created with an enum.

Comment: Sadly, some comments here were deleted. They helped me with two links, please add again if possible! Thx

Comment: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/586224/2587435), [link2](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_3_1-Hints-on-Writing-XML-Schemas.html#Don%27t%20Use%20Anonymous%20Types)

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying `typesafeEnumBase`. This is what I normally do when generating mappings:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="mySchema.xsd" 
    node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:globalBindings
        fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty="false"
        typesafeEnumBase="xs:string"
        typesafeEnumMemberName="generateName" 
        generateIsSetMethod="true">
        <xjc:noValidator />
        <xjc:noValidatingUnmarshaller />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>

    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="my.package.name"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

However I don't think this is the cause.

Since my `maven-jaxb2-plugin` works and `xjc` via Ant does not, the question, what is the difference.
Actually, `strict`, `verbose` and `extension` settings should make no difference for enums.

However it may be that `maven-jaxb2-plugin` uses a newer version of `xjc` than you're using with enum. Please try to update your `xjc` and see if it helps.

Comment: I will keep both in mind (typesafeEnumBase and xjc-update). As I am using a pre-configured workspace and my time is running out, I will change the xsd not to use anonymous enums.

Comment: OK. Using JAXB-2.2.7-Jar's didn't help :-(

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="ProblemType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="normalAttribute" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="enumAttribute">
                <xs:simpleType name="problemTypeEnum">
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_1" />
                        <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_2" />
                        <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_3" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="workingEnum">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_1" />
            <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_2" />
            <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_3" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="MyWorkingType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="normalAttribute" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="enumAttribute" type="workingEnum" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I generated the class by this maven plugin

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>commun-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generateDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</generateDirectory>
                            <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                            <strict>false</strict>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

ProblemTypeEnum.java

```
@XmlType(name = "problemTypeEnum")
@XmlEnum
public enum ProblemTypeEnum {

    VALUE_1,
    VALUE_2,
    VALUE_3;

    public String value() {
        return name();
    }

    public static ProblemTypeEnum fromValue(String v) {
        return valueOf(v);
    }

}
```

---

If you can change the structure .. this is the xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="ProblemType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="normalAttribute" nillable="true"
                type="xs:boolean" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="enumAttribute"
                type="problemTypeEnum" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="problemTypeEnum">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_1" />
            <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_2" />
            <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_3" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="workingEnum">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_1" />
            <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_2" />
            <xs:enumeration value="VALUE_3" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="MyWorkingType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="normalAttribute" nillable="true"
                type="xs:boolean" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="enumAttribute"
                type="workingEnum" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: OK. I use an ant-sxript in eclipse without having maven installed (not my decision). I will add this in my question, maybe there is something wrong. Thx so far!

Comment: I added an attribute name at your inner complex type .. name="problemTypeEnum". Have you added?

Comment: I tried that before and now again:
[xjc] [ERROR] s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'name' cannot appear in element 'simpleType'...

Could you please try with strict on?

Comment: Yes with strict=true does not generates the enum, but will generate if you use the second xsd in my answer.

Comment: OK. Just to be sure. The reason, that your 2nd xsd works, maybe, that both (ProblemType and WorkingType) use the same working solution ;-)

Comment: yes is the same solution. Maven allow a workaround, but the good solution is the second. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61119/discussion-between-xstian-and-sammy).